# What would cause image replacement class to fail in IE7 only?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am attempting to use the **HTML5 Boilerplate system (http://html5boilerplate.com/)** for a client's website, but I am having trouble with the built in .ir class when the site is viewed in certain browsers and on certain devices. 
Namely **IE7** and some (or all) Blackberries based on feedback and testing on my end.  The main nav and other elements of the design are not appearing / are not navigable in these situations. 
The client is a restaurant that caters to a large business district, so unfortunately a ton of their prospects and customers are on corporate systems still using IE7 and are unable to use the site, as-is.

**Here is a link to the relevant page(s):**
[www.vb3restaurant.com](http://vb3restaurant.com)

[vb3restaurant.com/index-pizza.html](http://vb3restaurant.com/index-pizza.html)

**Here is the .ir class that I believe to be the issue (though it could be something else):**

**.ir { display: block; border: 0; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: left; direction: ltr; *line-height: 0; }**

Would be quite appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction as to what is "breaking" or a better/cross browser/IE friendly way for me to accomplish this design, with image replacement or some other technique.

I am not an expert programmer by any means, but I have put up a few sites and have worked with a few different frameworks, CMS's, etc.  I have attempted looking on this site and elsewhere for answers, so I apologize in advance if I am missing an obvious thread that answers this question or if I have asked it in the wrong place or incorrectly.
And of course- thanks in advance for your time and help!

Best,
AB

Comment: `"What would cause image replacement class to fail in IE7 only?"` The fact that it is IE7.

Comment: agreed. i sent client a link to that site that started charging an "ie7 tax" to show them i wasnt just being crazy/lazy.

Comment: :-/ I don't see those menu items using IE8, either.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  do you know why it would be this way in IE in general then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ir` class is hiding the content with `text-indent:-999em` (improvement: http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/).

But the images that replace those items have new `nth-child` selectors that are not recognised by IE7, or IE8: http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/.  The rendering engines in these browsers pre-date the `nth-child` selector unfortunately.

You can either write a jQuery shim to patch your selectors: http://verboselogging.com/2010/01/17/making-nth-child-work-everywhere.  Or rewrite your selectors for all browsers, giving the menu items ids or class-names.

Sucks right?  Well, some think that of image-replacement! (particularly for low-bandwidth mobile devices)  So... you could also forget using image-raplacement for IE7/8 using an IE-specific stylesheet to style your plain text.

Comment: Yes. Sucks indeed.  I had wanted to avoid the whole image-replacement mess in the first place, but still not sure of best practices, especially when using fonts that are not stock. (I am using a condensed Helvetica I believe).  I was also afraid the nth selectors wouldn't fly, but tried  my luck anyway and by the time I learned about my IE-Fail, the site had been live for weeks. I will read the articles you link and try to rework everything based on your advice.  Thank you so much. The Stack community never fails to impress!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is this rule:

```
#mainNav ul li:nth-child(1) a {
display: block;
background-image: url(../images/home-nav-test.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 40px -35px;
}
```

Use classes on each nav item instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I had read something along the lines of, "shockingly, nth selectors do work with IE, blah, blah"...but I should have known this was too fancy a feature for the old gal.  I can't up-vote because my rep is too low, but this is much appreciated.  I am going to accept the other answer only because it covers a little more ground.  I am in your debt!